# Unwanted 1px line on the bottom of a bootstrap navbar and creating a navbar side gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**1)**

So I'm attempting to get my navbar with bootstrap all set up, and unfortunately there appears to be a 1px line at the bottom that I can't seem to get rid of.  Can anyone suggest any solutions?

**2)**

Also, is there a way to get a gap on each side of the navbar, but only if the viewport is above 768px?  I'm able to achieve this effect by moving the  outside the beginning  tag, but like I said I want the navbar to move back up when the website is viewed on a mobile device.

**Here's my code:** http://pastebin.com/zHP09rNu

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the pixel border you need to either set `border: 0;` or `border-color: transparent;` on the `.navbar` element. 
E.g:

```
.navbar {
      background-color: #99ccff; 
  border: 0;
}
```

Regarding your second point, you could set the width of the navbar to less than 100% and add a margin either side.

**Demo available here:** http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/CHJAg

Comment: Perfect, both of your solutions worked.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rolling with Bootstrap 3.3.6, and using LESS variables, simply set the @navbar-default-border variable to control your navbar border.  More on this can be found here - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

```
@navbar-default-border:none;
```